# JQuery .click .hide div with divs inside it

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the script to hide #homepage and the 3 divs inside it when the user clicks on #homepage-alpha

```
#alpha { display:none; }

$("#homepage-alpha").click(function(){ 
   $("#homepage").hide(); 
   $("#alpha").show(); 
});

<div id="homepage">
   <div id="homepage-alpha"></div>
   <div id="homepage-bravo"></div>
   <div id="homepage-charlie"></div>
</div>

<div id="alpha">
</div>
```

Comment: Your code should be in a script tag, and in a $(document).ready block

Comment: what's the problem with your code, is it not working ?

Comment: [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/tmfLG/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do

```
    ...
    <script>       
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#homepage-alpha").on('click',function(){ 
       $("#homepage").hide(); 
       $("#alpha").show(); 
      });
   });
   </script>
```

Even if when you put scripts just before the body, it pretty surely run after DOM is ready.

Comment: SOLVED ! Thank You for your help :) Here is the final solution :    $("#home-squbo").load("system/controls/home-squbo.php").click(function(){ $("#home").hide(); $("#squbo").show(); });

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
    #alpha { display:none; }

    <div id="homepage">
       <div id="homepage-alpha"></div>
       <div id="homepage-bravo"></div>
       <div id="homepage-charlie"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="alpha">
    </div>

    <script>       
    $("#homepage-alpha").click(function(){ 
       $("#homepage").hide(); 
       $("#alpha").show(); 
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: While this will typically work, it's good practice to wrap that whole script inside of a $(document).ready(function() { [code] }); Also as mentioned in the comments. It's also a good idea to add type="text/javascript" to the opening <script> tag.

Comment: Squbo.com

#squbo-exit works ( just click the big squbo area )
#dennisrodman does not work ( click dennis when he appears top right ) #dennisrodman is inside #home-20

    $("#home-20").load("system/controls/home-20.php");
    var refreshId = setInterval(function() { $("#home-20").load('system/controls/home-20.php?randval='+ Math.random()); }, 20000);

    $("#squbo-exit").load("system/controls/squbo-exit.php").click(function(){ $("#squbo").hide(); $("#home").show(); });

    $("#dennisrodman").load("system/controls/squbo-exit.php").click(function(){ $("#home").hide(); $("#squbo").show(); });

Comment: update the question maybe? :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <style>
  #alpha { display:none; }
 </style>
 </head>
    <body>
    <div id="homepage">
       <div id="homepage-alpha"></div>
       <div id="homepage-bravo"></div>
       <div id="homepage-charlie"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="alpha">
    </div>

    <script>       
    $("#homepage-alpha").click(function(){ 
       $("#homepage").hide(); 
       $("#alpha").show(); 
    });
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html and js code is good, just use in the right way.

```
<div id="homepage">
   <div id="homepage-alpha"></div>
   <div id="homepage-bravo"></div>
   <div id="homepage-charlie"></div>
</div>

<div id="alpha">
```

```
<script> 
$(function() {
  $("#homepage-alpha").click(function(){ 
     $("#homepage").hide(); 
     $( "#alpha" ).show(); 
  });
});
</script>
```

Chek this working example
[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naCPv/1/)